# Unable to Connect to just Google Servers

Tags: dns, internet

I am in an extremely strange problem. I am unable to connect to **just** Google Servers. I am not able to access any site related to Google, Google.com | YouTube | Google+ | Webmaster Tools | jQuery CDN, nothing is working. I am able to open any other website (as I am posting this question on SuperUser), even the Google DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) are offline.

Please Help!!

Update 1: Google DNS are back online, YouTube is back online. But website on domain google.com is not working (ex: play.google.com, maps.google.com, google.com/search, etc).

Update 2: I am able to access Google.com (only) with (one of) its IP addresss(s) listed below:

```
74.125.227.41
74.125.227.46
74.125.227.32
74.125.227.33
74.125.227.34
74.125.227.35
74.125.227.36
74.125.227.37
74.125.227.38
74.125.227.39
74.125.227.40
```

Update 3: <strike>I consulted my friends nearby and they said that they are also experiencing the same problem. Seams like this is a major problem in this area (or India !!)</strike> The Problem is Now Solved!! I am able to open Google.com

Comment: Can you please provide us with more information about the context of this problem?  Where is this happening?  How is it set up?

Comment: About 10 min ago, I was using Google DNS as primary DNS, I noticed it was failing to connect, I changed the DNS to my ISP provided data and it was working normally except using any Google Website. (Maybe Important) I am living in India.

Comment: Any chance of malware messing with your DNS settings or hosts file?

Comment: No, I guess no. I have Bitdefender Internet Security 2013, also I have tried scanning the PC with other antivirus live disks (The live disk was able to update). I have manually checked the hosts file, it only has entries that I have added earlier, I have even tried resetting the hosts file. No error over there.

Comment: What was the problem? Was is a local ISP issue?

Comment: I myself dont know about the problem yet, seams like it was a problem with **Google**, as many many people were experiencing issues. I guess it was not ISP issue as people with other ISPs were also experiencing this issue.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was at Google's end, so there was nothing to solve at the OP's end and there is no solution that would be useful to others.